# $scope.$on not triggering after $rootScope.$broadcast in angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This may be the repeated question but the workaround I found for this issue is not working in my case thats why I am posting the question.

I've following **service:**

```
appRoot.service('MyService', function($rootScope) {
    var Messenger = {
        Temp: "",
        TempId:"",
        tempMethod: function(Id) {
            TempId = Id;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('FirstCtrlMethod');
        }
    };
    return Messenger ;
});
```

In **second controller:**

```
appRoot.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, $location, MyResource, NotificationService, MyService) {
 $scope.invokeFirstCtrl= function() {
        var Id = '2';
        MyService.tempMethod(Id);
});
```

In **first controller:**

```
appRoot.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, $compile, $filter, $modal, $sce, $location, NotificationService, MyService) {
$scope.$on('FirstCtrlMethod', function () {        
        alert('I am from frist controller');
    });
});
```

**Problem:** The line *"$rootScope.$broadcast('FirstCtrlMethod');"* is executing as expected but it is not causing to fire event *"$scope.$on('FirstCtrlMethod', function () {.."* in the first controller.
I've used the differenct services in many places in my app in the same way and they are workig fine, I am not understanding why it is not working here.

Comment: are both controller instantiated when you are testing this??

Comment: Have you tried `$emit` instead of `$broadcast`? or just `$rootScope.$on`

Comment: Yah I've tried both .$emit and $rootScope.$on but still its not working

Comment: As pointed by @harish I was not initiating the first controller. Thats preventing the propogation of the event. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

putting comment as an answer...

I guess the other controller which is supposed to receive the event is not yet instatiated when you are $broadcasting the event.

Please try instantiating the other controller

Comment: how to instatiate that controller?

Comment: @satishkumarV You just need to make sure your controller is inside your app directive ("ng-app") and everything was correctly bound. For instance, `app.controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below working example

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('MyService', function($rootScope) {
  var Messenger = {
    Temp: "",
    TempId: "",
    tempMethod: function(Id) {
      TempId = Id;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('FirstCtrlMethod');
    }
  };
  return Messenger;
});

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {

  $scope.invokeFirstCtrl = function() {
    var Id = '2';
    MyService.tempMethod(Id);

  };
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.$on('FirstCtrlMethod', function() {
    alert('I am from frist controller');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <button ng-click="invokeFirstCtrl()">Invoke</button>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">


  </div>
</div>
```