# Second Controller not responding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason, the second Controller isn't receiving the data from the Service.
I'm trying to make the communication between two Controllers using one Service for it.

The View:

```
  <div class="btn-wrapper" ng-controller="FirstController">
    <a ng-href="" ng-click="doPath()" id="go" class="button">GO!</a>
  </div>
```

The FirstController.js:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('FirstController', function($scope, sharedService) {

    $scope.doPath = sharedService.searchPath;
});
```

The sharedService:

```
angular.module('myServices', [])
.service('sharedService', function($rootScope) {
  this.searchPath = function() {
    console.log("I got the service!");
    $rootScope.$broadcast('Search', {
      data: 'something'
    });
  }    
});
```

And the SecondController.js

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('SecondController', function(sharedService, $scope) {
    $scope.$on('Search', function(event, data){
      console.log(data);
      //this.search(); => I intent to run this function after this
    });
});
```

The event is dispatched by a button in the View, that calls the `doPath()` function. This function does communication with the Service `sharedService` and the message "I got the service" is displayed.

However, the app stops here. And the communication between Service and the second Controller, using `$rootScope.$broadcast`, seems that not happening (the data isn't showing on console, neither any error).

I found some solutions here. I have tried already all of answers, so the problem is not the same, cause still not working.

**EDIT**

The ngRoute is here (app.js):

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'myServices'])
.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'FirstController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Comment: Just an idea here... you are broadcasting to `$rootScope`, but your controller has the listener on the `$scope`. Have you tried to pass `$rootScope` as parameter on your controller definition and add the listener to that?...

Comment: At first glance, sharedService.searchPath is a function and you don't seem to be executing it. Try $scope.doPath = sharedService.searchPath();

Comment: @David Espino, yes I tried. The same result...

Comment: @ruedamanuel It displays the "I got the service" without any event! But it keeps stopped at the same place. It seems that it doesn't reach out the second Controller for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$scope.$on not triggering after $rootScope.$broadcast in angular service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728072/scope-on-not-triggering-after-rootscope-broadcast-in-angular-service)

Comment: Try adding the $scope.$on listener in the first controller to verify what the others are saying about controller instances. If it fires when the listener is present in the first controller then your problem is definitely a lack of second controller instance.

Comment: Try $rootScope.$emit instead of $rootScope.$broadcast; and try $rootScope.$on instead of $scope.$on.

Comment: And where is ng-controller="SecondController"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone suggested 'Instantiation' of the Second controller is needed.

```
<div ng-controller="firstController">
    //code
</div>

<div ng-controller="secondController">
    //code
</div>
```

Like above.

I know you have used 'ngRoute'. Until you change your view the **second controller** will not be loaded in 'ngRoute' whereas in **above code both the controllers are in the same view**. That is why above code works and 'ngRoute' does not.

Comment: But how about my ngRoute? Do I need to exclude the controller from there, and instantiate only on View? Or can I let it there (and using both of ways)? I realized that using both of them works, but is it a good practice?

Comment: @Atoyansk You can use either of the ways. It is not obligatory to have controller.

Answer (score 0):

SecondController is not instantiated by Angular because you are referring only  FirstController from html. You need to instantiate the SecondController on the same html using parent child or sibling relationship depending on your application.

Comment: in fact I did not instantiate the FirstController as I demonstrated (it was a way to make it more readable). I do using ngRoute. In that case, how would I instantiate both Controllers? I edited my question including the ngRoute code.

Comment: You can use the html as per your current design like below- 
<div class="btn-wrapper" ng-controller="FirstController">
 <div ng-controller="SecondController">
      <a ng-href="" ng-click="doPath()" id="go" class="button">GO!</a>
 </div>
  </div>